# Tips for Finding Bamboo Pipes?

Tags: the-tribez

I have a quest that is blocking progress for a number of other quests.  This is:

> Take 5 bamboo pipes from enemies or find them in the trees.

I think it's fair to say that the developer, GIGL, would prefer you to give up and just buy them through in-game micro transactions.  Barring that, is there any way to encourage enemies to attack the village or to spur tree growth?  It's relatively rare for either to happen which makes finding the pipes pretty discouraging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try and do is keep the huts instead of destroying them. there will be greater numbers of attacks by them just because there are more huts. trees take too long to grow back once you remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I got past this one eventually, but it was frustrating.  No trick, just have to wait it out.  Murlods were more likely to drop the bamboo, but keep trying trees.

I don't spend money on the game, so their attempt at getting us to use the gems failed, at least for me.